# setPriority() sometimes don't seem to fire startAt().endAt().on("child_added")

Tags: firebase

Use `on("child_added")` with `startAt()` and `endAt()` for some regions.

```
rootRef.startAt(0).endAt(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {...});
rootRef.startAt(10).endAt(20).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {...});
```

And move an item from a region to another using `setPriority()` or `setWithPriority()`. Some cases "child_added" fired, but some other cases didn't fire.

Try an example at jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9SJv/16/

You may see that:

Move `12` -> `0.2` will be added in `startAt(0).endAt(1).on("child_added"`

Move `12` -> `0.8` won't be added in `startAt(0).endAt(1).on("child_added"`

Comment: Engineer at Firebase here. Thanks for the great repro steps - we're digging into this issue and will follow-up once we've fully diagnosed and made progress on this. Looks like a legitimate bug though. Thanks!

Comment: Rob, I appreciate your team take the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. It's definitely a bug on our end. I've filed it in our internal tracker, along with steps to repro. It may be a little while, but we will fix it.

In the meantime, if there's not a ton of data at that location, you could use value events at rootRef.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Greg, did you fix the bug already? I can't reproduce with the jsfiddle .

Comment: We did in fact fix this, I think the change went out on Friday. Apologies, I'm a little behind on updating stackoverflow responses.