# Firebase: Priority set to null on server but not on client when setting grandchild

Tags: firebase

To reproduce, check out http://jsfiddle.net/3aR7N/16/ .  First click "Set child and grandchild," which sets a child to a priority and then sets a grandchild within it.  Then click "Show Local Values" and you'll see that the child still seems to have a priority of 123.  Click that as many times as you like - the priority always comes back as 123.

Once you're satisfied that your local priority really is 123, refresh the whole page.  You'll be dismayed to see that the priority now is null.

I can believe this is a concurrency issue, with certain effects of the `set` happening in different orders.  Is the expected behavior that setting a child would clear the priority of the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the easy test case! This is indeed a bug. The client and server are handling this case differently, which is why you're seeing this inconsistent behavior.

Note that this only occurs if you "setWithPriority" a primitive value, and then write deeper in the tree (which deletes that primitive value).

**Update:** This has now been fixed.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that note - this will help me move on in my project by initially setting to `{"blah":"blah"}` or something until the actual fix is in.  LOVING Firebase so far, btw!  Would you be interested in my GWT wrapper?

Comment: This seems to related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437229/setpriority-sometimes-dont-seem-to-fire-startat-endat-onbhild-added

Comment: We'd love your GWT wrapper. Would you be willing to open-source it up on github?

Comment: Also - I'm not sure why you need to set an "initial" value at all. You don't need to create a path before writing to it's children. If you simply write to /a/b/c/d, all of the intermediate nodes come into existence automatically. I can't think of a good reason to write a value and then immediately write a deeper one...

Comment: This is fixed now. You can try the jsfiddle again and you should see the child priority remains as 123.

Thanks again for the easy test case!

Comment: Derek Thurn at Google Open Sourced GWT Wrapper for Firebase here: https://github.com/thurn/firebase-xplatform though latest commit is on April 2014